# Android onRequestPermissionsResult is getting called only on Activity but not on Fragment

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have an Activity which contains a fragment. I am requesting contact permission from the activity as follows:

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);`

and from fragment I am requesting camera permission like this:

`requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);`

I have `onRequestPermissionsResult` method on both the fragment and the activity. The problem is, even if I request permission from the fragment, the `onRequestPermissionsResult` from the activity gets called. The `onRequestPermissionsResult` from the fragment doesn't get called (but it gets called if I remove `onRequestPermissionsResult` from the activity). Is there any way to appropriate `onRequestPermissionsResult` method?

Comment: Did you call `super. onRequestPermissionsResult(...)` in your activity?

Comment: @ridsatrio forgot to do that. Tried now and it worked :D thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to call `super.onRequestPermissionsResult(...)` when you overrides the method in your `Activity`.

That said, one other way to solve this is to manually notify the `Fragment`s that you have within your activity:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    final List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

..and just have your fragments respond by doing the appropriate action if the `requestCode` sent is theirs.